# MDT 2013 - Language to Install Missing

Tags: windows-7, deployment, mdt

I am currently preparing and testing my first MDT deployment at work. Up to now we have been using WDS with custom images and unattend files.

I have set up the MDT deployment share and imported a Windows 7 Pro 64 bit installation from an original MS ISO.

I have made some changes to the customsettings.ini file but I am not able to automate the locale screen. I need it to install United Kingdom English but the default selection is empty and it only allows me to manually choose US. My ini below:

```
[Settings]
Priority=Default
Properties=MyCustomProperty

[Default]
OSInstall=Y
SkipCapture=YES
SkipAdminPassword=YES
SkipProductKey=YES
SkipComputerBackup=YES
SkipBitLocker=YES
SkipDomainMembership=YES
SkipSummary=YES
KeyboardLocale=0809:00000809
UILanguage=en-GB
UserLocale=en-GB
TimeZone=GMT Standard Time
SkipUserData=YES
SkipCapture=YES
SkipProductKey=YES
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the skip local selection to your system otherwise it will still ask what you want to do and your settings do nothing.

`SkipLocaleSelection=YES`

---

I have added mine above the local settings like this:

```
[Settings]
Priority=Default
Properties=MyCustomProperty
DeploymentType=NEWCOMPUTER

[Default]
OSInstall=Y
SkipCapture=NO
SkipAdminPassword=YES
SkipProductKey=YES
SkipComputerBackup=YES
SkipBitLocker=YES
SkipDeploymentType=YES
SkipApplications=YES
SkipAppsOnUpgrade=YES

JoinWorkGroup=Elliot Labs



 SkipLocaleSelection=YES



 KeyboardLocale=0409:00000409

UserLocale=en-US
UILanguage=en-US

SkipTimeZone=YES
TimeZoneName=Eastern Standard Time

SkipSummary=YES
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the MDT help files, keyboardlocale should be in both the customsettings.ini and the bootstrap.ini. There is also a keyboardlocalePE setting that can be used, depending on whether the locale screen you are trying to automate is in the WindowsPE part of the process.  [This thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c84c1fa9-4097-40cd-9912-343654011989/change-language-in-mdt-litetouch-deployment-environment) on the TechNet forums may prove helpful.

Additionally, since you have been using unattend files with WDS, you can edit your unattend file in MDT and manually add the settings that worked before. Right click on the task sequence in MDT and choose properties. Go to the last tab, ‘OS Info’, and click on the ‘Edit Unattend.xml’ button. This will open your unattend file in the Windows System Image Manager, where you can make your changes.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Here is my locale info.

**CustomSettings**

```
;Locale
KeyboardLocale=en-US
UserLocale=en-US
UILanguage=en-US
SkipTimeZone=YES
TimeZoneName=Central Standard Time
TimeZone=020
```

**Bootstrap**

```
KeyboardLocale=en-US
```